# Unable to resolve dependency error while integrating any liabrary in android studio 3.1.3

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dependencies

Recently i have updated android studio to 3.1.3 everytime i am getting the "Unable to resolve Ddependency" error. Stuck with this problem already i have wasted lotts of days solving this error but nothing works. Please help me to resolve this error.I have uploaded my gradle file here and also the error log.

**Below is my gradle file:**
`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

```
android {



compileSdkVersion 27

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.administrator.myapplication1"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
`}`

`repositories {`
    `maven {`
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:2.0.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation project(':library')
api 'com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
`
```

Error log:

```
Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download okhttp.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0): Skipped due to earlier error
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download okhttp.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0): Skipped due to earlier error
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download okhttp.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0): Skipped due to earlier error
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not download okhttp.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0): Skipped due to earlier error
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download okhttp.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0): Skipped due to earlier error
Open File
Show Details
`
```

Project(build.gradle):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {

        maven {
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/florent37/maven"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: please add your Module app build.gradle as well

Comment: this is app level build.gradle

Comment: yes there is one more gradle file for modules

Comment: Check whether your offline Mode is unchecked in Gradle settings.

Comment: the latest available version of the OkHttp is 3.10.0 and not the 3.11.0

Comment: you mean to say project level gradle file??

Comment: offline mode is unchecked.

Comment: yes monali...please add that

Comment: i have done all the things like changing versiosns n all but nothing work for me.

Comment: ok i will add that.

Comment: @Monali did you try following steps:- https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1141

Comment: yes i have tried.

Comment: I have updated my code please have a look.

Comment: @Monali Try to change your google gms version in project buil.gradle :- classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1' and sync/build again

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari now i am getting this error "Read timed out"

Comment: Have you tried clean rebuild your project? If that didn't work try to invalidate cheches/Restart from the file menu

Comment: Done all these steps.nothing helping me

Answer (score 1):

```
maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
```

Please add this line in your project level gradle file under repositories. because the library circularReveal is using repo from jitpack. Also remove circular Reveal and rebuild the project, it should be able to build properly.

Project Level Gradle

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App Level Gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yourcomp.stackoverflow"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
}
```

Comment: after adding this i am getting this error "Read timed out"

Comment: Make sure you have the access to jitpack.io from your network. Could you try once by removing these two lines and recheck it once.  implementation('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:2.0.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}

Comment: how to check this??

Comment: Just remove that library once and rebuild the project. If it is building properly, there is a problem with it.

Comment: I am able to buld your gradle file successfully if I removed that library.

Comment: Check Now I pasted my gradle files

Answer (score 0):

You Just need to update your SDK tools according to the library, and it will work.